# In C, does * also mean the same thing as void when used as a function argument?

Tags: c

For example, look at the following (abstract) declaration :

```
int (*) (*)
```

// pointer to a function returning an int and taking no arguments

(which I got from the following site : http://www.vineetgupta.com/blog/deciphering-complex-c-declarations)

I thought that only void means no arguments. Does this really mean the same thing as :

```
int (*) (void)
```

If so, where does it state that * can be used to specify no arguments?

Also, am I correct in assuming that abstract declarations such as this only exist for type casting? If so then it must be invalid in its current form since it lacks the surrounding parenthesis right? So `int(*)(void)` is invalid, but `(int(*)(void))` is valid, no?

Comment: It's a pointer to a function returning `int` and taking a pointer as argument. It's not legal C, as the pointer argument must be a pointer to *something*.

Comment: I feel `int (*) (*)` means nothing (error) , `int (*) (int*)` is possible. If you what an ood declaration `int (*) (int, ...) ;` may be correct, (the linked page is some guy's web, not a standard page I think)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> pointer to a function returning an int and taking no arguments

That's not right - the function takes a pointer as its argument, but since the type specifier is missing, the base type of the pointer is assumed to be `int`. This is ancient (pre-standard) behavior, some compilers allow it, others don't.

> I thought that only void means no arguments. Does this really mean the same thing as :

```
int (*) (void)
```

No, it doesn't, for the reason explained above.

> Also, am I correct in assuming that abstract declarations such as this only exist for type casting?

No, they can be used in function argument lists in a function declaration too. So,

```
int factorial(int);
```

is perfectly fine, so is

```
void qsort(void *, size_t, size_t, int (*)(const void *, const void *));
```

Comment: +1 What I specifically learn from you is, how to answer a question. Yours is a very cool one ; addressing every problem clearly and uniquely. :)

Comment: @PHIfounder Oh, that's kind of you. Thanks. :) (Not everyone thinks that...)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

```
 int (*) (*)
```

results in an error when i tried in visual studio and its not the way of declaring.

If you want a function pointer to return an integer data with pointer as argument the correct way of doing it is below.

```
 int(*foo)(datatype *).
```

where data type can be

```
  int ,float,char etc
```

and **void** and ***** are not the same .